# Is There A Simple PHP Web Server

Tags: php, web-server, unix

Is there anything that is a dead-simple PHP web server for Linux that literally takes a single PHP file and serves it via port 80. Don't want to configure a full blown web server like apache, lighttpd, or nginx. Just need to serve a single PHP script, and don't need vhosts. Would be awesome if it worked like:

```
$ simple-php-web-server myscript.php
```

Comment: This showed up in a Google search.  http://nanoweb.si.kz/

Comment: Please tell me this is for development or testing, and won't be accessible from the Internet...

Comment: busbyjon made a very simple PHP (2 script) webserver: https://github.com/busbyjon/php-web-server

Answer (score 17):

PHP 5.4+ includes a new command ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)):

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Which will launch a simple PHP web server.

You can also make the web server accessible on port 8000 to *any* interface with:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: This is documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 3):

You need a webserver - there's no way around that if you want to access the output of the scripts via http.

There are some very minimal webservers which will run PHP via CGI. e.g. [monkey httpd](http://monkey-project.com/) (last time I had a look this compiled to 49kb) and which can run as daemons or via [x]inetd.

You might also have a look at [nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/) - a webserver written in PHP.

ISR there's some discussion over whether PHP6 will be bundled with a minimal webserver for dev/testing.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of but you can put one together fairly easily if you know some Java...

My first thought is if you can't find an existing solution then roll your own.
Look at Netty http://www.jboss.org/netty it can do this (In particular the http server example http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html#examples) and all you'd need is to use one of their examples to bind to port 80. Invoke the php command from java and feed the results back ( http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2008/08/making-system-call-in-java.html)...Simple hack.

In reality though if you're putting this in a serious production environment then I'd highly urge you reconsider an established solution like the ones you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a full http server, another option would be serving your script through xinetd (an example [here](http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/building-network-services-with-php-and-xinetd/) ).
But this way no http headers will be used.

Comment: So it's not really http then?

Answer (score 0):

[NanoWeb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/) might be of use to you.